# Multiple force networks clustered around locations

Tags: d3.js, force-layout

I have a visualization I'm building that seeks to show collaborations among academic disciplines at workshops. There are seven locations, and I'd like each location to be a central node to any of the disciplines involved -- a sort of "spoke" pattern like this, which will eventually be mapped:

[image: Network]

I've gotten part of the way there in building the network, and I've been looking at Bostock's [Force Layout Multiples](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1804889) for some inspiration. But I'm still a bit stuck.

The network looks like this:

```
var width = 1200,
    height = 650;

var color = d3.scale.category20();

d3.csv("./d/network.csv", function(error, csv_data) {

  // array of nodes
  var nodes = {};

  // compute nodes from links
  csv_data.forEach(function(link) {
      link.source = nodes[link.source] || (nodes[link.source] = {name: link.source});
      link.target = nodes[link.target] || (nodes[link.target] = {name: link.target});
  });

  var force = d3.layout.force()
    .nodes(d3.values(nodes))
    .links(csv_data)
    .size([width, height])
    .linkDistance(60)
    .charge(-900)
    .on("tick", tick)
    .start();

  var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

  // add the edges
  var path = svg.append("g").selectAll("path")
    .data(force.links())
  .enter().append("path")
    .attr("class", "link");

  // define the nodes
  var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
    .data(force.nodes())
  .enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "node")
    .on("mouseover", mouseover)
    .on("mouseout", mouseout)
    .call(force.drag);

  // add the nodes
  node.append("circle")
    .attr("r", 5)
    .style("fill", function(d) { console.log('d: ', d); return color(d.name); });

  // add the text 
  node.append("text")
    .attr("x", 12)
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .text(function(d) { return d.name; });

  // ========================== Functions ==========================

  // add the edges
  function tick() {
    path.attr("d", function(d) {
        var dx = d.target.x - d.source.x,
            dy = d.target.y - d.source.y,
            dr = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
        return "M" + 
            d.source.x + "," + 
            d.source.y + "A" + 
            dr + "," + dr + " 0 0,1 " + 
            d.target.x + "," + 
            d.target.y;
    });

    node
        .attr("transform", function(d) { 
            return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });
  }

  // resize nodes on mouseover and mouseout
  function mouseover() {
    d3.select(this).select("circle").transition()
        .duration(750)
        .attr("r", 8);
  }  
  function mouseout() {
    d3.select(this).select("circle").transition()
        .duration(750)
        .attr("r", 5);
  }
});
```

Which gives me the full network:

[image: Full network]

But now I'm after the separated and independent networks, so for example although the full network graph shows Stanford and Cambridge sharing "chemistry," I want Stanford and Cambridge to appear on their own with each having a "chemistry" node that isn't shared. The data looks something like this:

```
source,target
"Berlin","Architecture and Urban Planning"
"Berlin","Human-Computer Interaction"
"Berlin","Informatics"
"Berlin","Sociology"
"Berlin","Sociology and Social Policy"
"Berlin","Informatics"
"Berlin","Industrial Design"
"Berlin","Engineering"
"Brussels","Medicine"
"Brussels","Sociology"
"Brussels","Engineering"
"Brussels","Genetics"
"Brussels","Science, Technology, and Society"
"Brussels","Urban Planning"
"Brussels","Gender and Neuroscience"
"Brussels","Informatics"
"Cambridge","Computer Science"
"Cambridge","Physics"
"Cambridge","Physics"
"Cambridge","Computer Science"
"Cambridge","Google Research"
"Cambridge","Linguistics"
"Cambridge","Pharmacology"
"Cambridge","History of Science"
"Cambridge","Biology"
"Cambridge","Computer Science"
"Cambridge","Neurobiology"
"Cambridge","Chemistry"
```

My question, I think, boils down to: should I iterate through the data to find the unique occurrences of `source` and `target`, or is `d3.nest` my friend? And how might I get started doing so?

Comment: It sounds to me like you would want to do some preprocessing outside of D3 here. In particular, it might be useful to run some other graph layout algorithm on it to get sensible defaults for the positions of the nodes -- in your picture it all looks a bit cluttered, and the force layout is not particularly good at mitigating this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you're indexing nodes by discipline (i.e. `nodes[link.target] = ...`) ensures uniqueness, but actually ends up creating too much uniqueness –– across the entire network. In other words, there is only one "Informatics" node, and that one ends up connected to all the cities in which it appears. Instead, you need to ensure uniqueness per city:

```
var key = link.target + '@' + link.source;
link.target = nodes[key] || (nodes[key] = {name: link.target});
```